# Change multi index to column

Tags: python, pandas

is there a way to convert the multiindex columns to normal value columns? I have a multiindexed table like that:

|  | level_0 | level_1 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | A |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | B |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | C |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | D |

I want to convert level_0 and level_1 to normal columns:

| ID | col0 | col1 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | A |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | B |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | C |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | D |

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: If this relates to pandas you should add an appropriate tag.

Comment: Are you using pandas? Also, it would be helpful if you can provide a code snippet representing the starting point for your problem.

Comment: Sorry, yes, pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) followed by [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

```py
# Setup
my_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([(0, 1, 2, 3), 
                                      (0, 0, 1, 1), 
                                      (0, 1, 0, 1)], 
                                      names=[None, 'level_0', 'level_1'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']}, index=my_index)
```

```py
>>> # level=['level_0', 'level_1'] works, too
>>> df = df.reset_index(level=[1, 2])
>>> df
   level_0  level_1 Value
0        0        0     A
1        0        1     B
2        1        0     C
3        1        1     D
```

To rename the columns, you can do

```py
>>> df.rename(columns={'level_0': 'col0', 'level_1': 'col1'})
   col0  col1 Value
0     0     0     A
1     0     1     B
2     1     0     C
3     1     1     D
```